# View virtualhost webpage on mobile

Tags: php, mobile, localhost

There are a lot of pages telling the basics, but now outside that please.
I think I'm missing a small thing or need more coffee.

I'm ABLE to access: localhost/agenda (agenda is in htdocs and runs fine).
I'm ABLE (?) to access by mobile: 192.168.1.12 , and also 192.168.1.12/agenda (I guess..) because I get the following error:

**Object not found! The request URL was not found [..] Apache/2.4.9 [..] PHP/5.5.11**

My mobile browser shows the correct versions, so I guess it has access right?
..
but not loading splash page or my webapplication. Any suggestions what to check?

(using xampp)

Comment: Solved the problem. Httpd-vhosts.conf (answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Allright, for the other developers meeting the exact same problem. 
I found the issue, and its logic, but you might missed it :)

Open file: C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

You gotta add stuff there. More information on
http://samminds.com/2012/07/zend-framework-2-installation-on-xampp-for-windows/

Search for: "Configuring apache virtual host"

Ready to go. It worked for me.